# IPython Notebook: Open/select file with GUI (Qt Dialog)

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

When you perform the same analysis in a notebook on different data files, may be handy to graphically select a data file.

In my python scripts I usually implement a QT dialog that returns the file-name of the selected file:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

def gui_fname(dir=None):
    """Select a file via a dialog and return the file name.
    """
    if dir is None: dir ='./'
    fname = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Select data file...", 
            dir, filter="All files (*);; SM Files (*.sm)")
    return fname[0]
```

However, running this function from an notebook

```
full_fname = gui_fname()
```

causes the kernel to die (and restart):

Interestingly, puttying this 3 command in 3 separate cells works

```
%matplotlib qt
full_fname = gui_fname()
%matplotlib inline
```

but when I put those commands in one single cell the kernel dies again.

This prevents  to create a function like `gui_fname_ipynb()` that transparently allows selecting a file with a GUI.

For convenience, I created a notebook illustrating the problem:

- [Open/select file with GUI (Qt Dialog)](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/anonymous/8138346)

Any suggestion on how to execute a dialog for file selection from within an IPython Notebook?

Answer (score 14):

Using Anaconda 5.0.0 on windows (Python 3.6.2, IPython 6.1.0), the following two options are both working for me.

#### OPTION 1: Entirely in a Jupyter notebook:

CELL 1:

```
%gui qt

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog

def gui_fname(dir=None):
    """Select a file via a dialog and return the file name."""
    if dir is None: dir ='./'
    fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Select data file...", 
                dir, filter="All files (*);; SM Files (*.sm)")
    return fname[0]
```

CELL 2:

```
gui_fname()
```

This is working for me but it seems a bit...fragile. If I combine these two things into the same cell, it crashes. Or if I omit the `%gui qt`, it crashes. If I "restart kernel and run all cells", it doesn't work. So I kinda like this other option...

#### MORE RELIABLE OPTION: Separate script that opens dialog box in a new process

(Based on mkrog code [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5798).)

PUT THE FOLLOWING IN A SEPARATE PYTHON SCRIPT CALLED `blah.py`:

```
from sys import executable, argv
from subprocess import check_output
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QApplication

def gui_fname(directory='./'):
    """Open a file dialog, starting in the given directory, and return
    the chosen filename"""
    # run this exact file in a separate process, and grab the result
    file = check_output([executable, __file__, directory])
    return file.strip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    directory = argv[1]
    app = QApplication([directory])
    fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Select a file...", 
            directory, filter="All files (*)")
    print(fname[0])
```

...AND IN YOUR JUPYTER NOTEBOOK

```
import blah
blah.gui_fname()
```

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 10 with Jupyter (Classic) Notebook v6.1.5, but it is kind of clunky, since I want the notebook to be self-contained.  So I use a iPython Notebook magic command "%%writefile <<< code above>>>" to write out the Python input cell source code above to a local file, and then import the module and run it in the next cell.  The Qt File Chooser opens as a "pop-behind" rather than a pop-up dialog, which is a bit of a hassle.  However, it works.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I have a universal code where it does its job without any problem. Here is my sugestion:

```
try:
    from tkinter import Tk
    from tkFileDialog import askopenfilenames
except:
    from tkinter import Tk
    from tkinter import filedialog

Tk().withdraw() # we don't want a full GUI, so keep the root window from appearing
filenames = filedialog.askopenfilenames() # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file

print (filenames)
```

hope it can be useful

Comment: Is it correct that all of these solutions only work if the jupyter lab instance is running on the same host as the browser?

Comment: This does not work with Jupyter Classic Notebook v6.1.5 or Spyder v4.2.3.  It hangs the iPythonNB kernel and requires restarting the server kernel.  I tried using it in Spyder, and it opens the Tkinter dialog, but only as a "pop-behind", and then after selecting a file, the filenames are never actually returned to the calling program.   This gets my downvote in 2021.

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour was a bug in IPython:

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/4997

that was fixed here:

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/5077

The function to open a gui dialog should work on current master and on the oncoming 2.0 release.

To date, the last 1.x version (1.2.1) **does not** include a backport of the fix.

**EDIT:** The example code still crashes IPython 2.x, see [this issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5798).