# How to show file selection dialog for server side files in JupyterLab/JupyterHub python notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I would like to show a file selection dialog, where users of my JupyterLab notebook
can select a file from their workspace (= files on server, not from their local computer).

If I would try to use some python library (tkinter, qt), that would try to open a GUI on the server.
However, I want to have a GUI on the client. Since the client runs in the browser, that
GUI needs to be based on html/javascript.

Furthermore, the files to be selected are located on the server. A list of existing
files can be shown with a system command (e.g. "!dir").

There seem to be widgets for file selection in JupyterLab:

https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/developer/ui_helpers.html#file-dialogs

JavaScript code (requires a build step of Jupyterlab extension; `FileDialog` needs to be imported from @jupyterlab/filebrowser; DocumentManager needs to be injected as plugin dependency from @jupyterlab/docmanager; ):

```
var { FileDialog } = require('@jupyterlab/filebrowser');

const dialog = FileDialog.getOpenFiles({
  manager, // IDocumentManager
  filter: model => model.type == 'notebook' // optional (model: Contents.IModel) => boolean
});

const result = await dialog;

if(result.button.accept){
  let files = result.value;
}
```

=>How can I use those widgets in my python code? Is there some extra python library for doing so?

Unfortunately `FileDialog` does not seem to be inlcuded in `ipywidgets`:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
print(dir(widgets))
```

**Related:**

https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyterlab-file-chooser-widget-server-side/4934/3

*ipywidgets*

- https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20List.html
- https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2018/10/24/working-with-jupyter-notebook-widgets/
- https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/2190

*qt and tkinter*

- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/162920/file-selection-button-for-jupyter-notebook
- [IPython Notebook: Open/select file with GUI (Qt Dialog)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20790926/ipython-notebook-open-select-file-with-gui-qt-dialog)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a workaround there is https://pypi.org/project/ipyfilechooser/

The file selection is not shown as extra dialog window but in
the output region of the notebook cell, also see:

https://github.com/crahan/ipyfilechooser/issues/31

Installation:

```
pip install ipyfilechooser
```

Usage:

```
from ipyfilechooser import FileChooser

fc = FileChooser()
display(fc)
```

---

```
fc.selected
```

Answer (score 0):

We have built a [FileBrowser component in Solara](https://solara.dev/api/file_browser) that solves this problem. It shows the files on the server:

```
import solara
solara.FileBrowser(directory="/Users/maartenbreddels/data/", on_file_open=print)
```

[image: screen capture of file browser]

It's a solara component, so if you want to use this in a classic ipywidgets application, use the [`.widget`](https://solara.dev/api/widget) method, like:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
widgets.VBox(
    children=[
        solara.FileBrowser.widget(directory="/Users/maartenbreddels/data/", on_file_open=print)
    ]
)
```